# How to get values from different forms in Apex

Tags: visualforce

I have a single Visualforce page where I include 2 pages through composition, body changes dynamically based on the action of the buttons. Button which is available in wizardButton (like next & previous). So now there are 2 forms available in page.

The form available in wizardBody
Another form available in wizardButton
Currently i'm able to navigate the pages back and forth, but the problem is not able to take the form values of the body when click the buttons in wizardButtons.

I even tried parameters in the controllers to get the value.

Could somebody help me how to solve this issue. Kindly let me know in case of any further details

```
<apex:page label="CreationWizard" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" title="Creation Wizard" controller="WizardController">

  <!- Body differs based on the action button -->
  <apex:composition template="{!wizardBody}" /> 
  <apex:composition template="{!wizardButton}"/>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Are your both pages using the same controller? If not - do this and you will be happy.

Comment: I'm using only same controller

Comment: Can somebody help me on the above topic